# I have ec2 instance with with only private IP how should i use capistrano for deployment

Tags: capistrano, capistrano3, rvm-capistrano

I have assign only private ip to my ec2 instance and want to use capistrano for deployment how should i use it 
i am not able to deploy using cap  deploy

Answer (score 0):

If you have public IP somewhere you can setup VPN server there and VPN clients on the ec2 and the machin from where you deploy. After thah you can access (deploy) ec2 trough its VPN IP address. 
Another workaround is ssh tunnel https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87432/ssh-to-private-ip